# masking heroku app from godaddy using cloudflare

Tags: heroku, cloudflare

I am trying to set up my herokupapp with my custom domain name from Godaddy.  I hav gone through the process of getting it wokring using a cname through cloudflare.

[image]

Everything is working.  However, when I go to my site at example.com my browser changes the url to example.herokuapp.com.
Going to:  http://www.example.com/ and www.example.com do work
I don't want this obviously, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's a good chance your application code is doing this. Does it know its own domain, e.g. so it can build links properly? What technology did you use to build it?

Comment: NextJs.  But the links aren't based on the domain.

Comment: Is it for the domain in your screenshot? I can get to `www.stackyourprops.com`, and the address doesn't update in my browser.

Comment: Yeah that is now working but without www it still shows up as herokuapp

Comment: Okay, I'm a bit confused. Your question says "when I go to my site at www.example.com or example.com my browser changes the url to example.herokuapp.com". Is that not correct? You have now edited it to add "Going to: http://www.example.com/ does work I don't want this obviously", but there's nothing obvious about that. What, _specifically_, don't you want?

Comment: When you go to stackyourprops.com it doesn't show tomskb.herokuapp.com in the browser

Comment: Okay, so it's _just_ the root domain that you're asking about? Because that's not what your question says.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, the other one started working halfway thrrough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't use an A record for your root domain](https://help.heroku.com/NH44MODG/my-root-domain-isn-t-working-what-s-wrong). Heroku doesn't provide static IP addresses, so whatever value you put there won't be valid for long.

Since you're using CloudFlare you should be able to set up a `CNAME` for your apex domain just like you did for your `www` subdomain. CloudFlare has a feature called [CNAME flattening](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169056-Understand-and-configure-CNAME-Flattening) that should make a CNAME on your root domain work as expected.

Regarding your comment that the `www` subdomain started working, that's typical of DNS changes. They take time to propagate. Give it some time.